# how to make DBLookupComboBox mouse wheel work

Tags: combobox, c++builder, mousewheel, c++builder-xe6

How to use the mouse wheel to move between listed items in the `DBLookupComboBox`? Like the way it does in `ComboBox`.

I am using c++builder xe6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it
for every one suffered the answer is simple

in FormMouseWheelDown event write this down

if (DBLookupComboBox1->Focused() == true)
      DBLookupComboBox1->Perform(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);

and in FormMouseWheelUp write

if (DBLookupComboBox1->Focused() == true)
      DBLookupComboBox1->Perform(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0);

that is it .. enjoy